# angular-fullstack generator failed to load template while running dist folder?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, yeoman-generator-angular, angular-fullstack

I am having issue which is like this in image [image]

This issue is random.if i again gulp build and start running the project with command

> grunt serve:dist

Now it may find the navbar.html but it will not find another template for another directive or routes.I am really confused.If i am right, i think the gulp hasnot minfied or compressed the html properly with $templateCache service.Please help.i am running node v5.0.0 and my npm is 3.5.1.The generator i am using is https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I have the same problem with gulp